# STM32G031 UFQFN28 programming

Tags: stm32

Iaccording to the datasheet, I understand that PA11 and PA12 are mapped by default, which don't have USART TX/RX function, it should be changed to PA9 and PA10.

AN2606 says that P9 and P10 can be used

Does it mean that the bootloader automatically switches to that function?, or the UFQFN28 packages cannot be programmed by pins 18 and 19 (PA9/PA10 [PA11/PA12])?
The datasheet says that yes, but I want to confirm that the 28 pin package can be programmed using pins 18 and 19 with uart, and if the only i2c that can be used for programming is that of PB6 and PB7 as the AN2606 sección of STM32G03x, 4x says??

Comment: The best way is for you to run STM32CubeIDE and use the configuration tool (STM32CubeMX) to try it out. All your questions will be self-answered.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the datasheet, reference manual or application note to say whether or not the ROM bootloader sets the remap bits in SYSCFG_CFGR1, so that PA9 and PA10 can be used on the low pin-count devices.  If they do, it will work, if they leave it at the default setting, it will not.

The only way you could find it out is to contact ST support, or to test it on an [evaluation board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-g031k8.html) yourself.  Testing it yourself will be quicker!

If you find out, please post an answer to your own question and accept it.